# ruby sequel and postgreSQL - too many clients (connections)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel, grape-api

I'm using the sequel gem inside a DB class that is used across my app (rack app) and it's instantiated only once.

The DB class initialises sequel once and has some methods I call, mainly read-only:

```
def initialize
  @psql ||= Sequel.connect('postgres://localhost/mydb')
end

def query_example
  @psql[:users].order(:time)
end
```

The app is basically an API. Something like:

```
class API < Grape::API
format :json

before do
  @db = Db.new
end

get '/' do
  @db.query_example
end
```

This works until I reach 100 connections in postgreSQL. I assume sequel is using some sort of connection pool but somehow is not freeing up the connections? I can see the 100 'selects' in the pg_stat_activity table with a status of 'idle'. However every new request fails with the following error:

**Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already**

```
/Users/lopezj2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sequel-4.22.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:236:in `initialize'
/Users/lopezj2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sequel-4.22.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:236:in `new'
/Users/lopezj2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sequel-4.22.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:236:in `connect'
/Users/lopezj2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sequel-4.22.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:101:in `make_new'
```

It looks like Sequel is trying to create a new connection in the pool, however, the app is not particularly chatty.

Answer (score 3):

You should create connection pool only once, and checkout a connection from the pool for each request, but in your code, you just create a new pool for each request.

You can change your DB class like this:

```
class DB
  class << self
    attr_reader :psql
  end

  # Note that @psql is a class instance variable
  @psql = Sequel.connect('postgres://localhost/mydb')

  def query_example
    DB.psql[:users].order(:time)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick. Maybe a silly question but I'm trying to understand why if I only create DB once, @psql initializes multiple times? I've even put a ||= in there...

Comment: In your original code, you call `Sequel.connect` inside the constructor. New instances initially don't have `@psql` before you call `@psql ||= Sequel.connect(...)`, so even you use `||=`, it's equivalent to use `=` except for a tiny performance loss. In my code, the `@psql` belongs to the class `DB`, not its instances. Since the class is loaded only once, the `@psql` is initialized only once.

Comment: P.S. Since `@psql` is now belongs to the `DB` class, the instances of `DB` cannot access it directly. That's why I provided a class level attribute accessor.